# Como modifico la nota de cada alumno luego de buscarlo

Tags: python

Hola me piden que se pueda cambiar las notas de los estudiantes ingresados
esto llevo del codigo

```
   alumnos={}

def agregar():
  n=int(input("cuantos alumnos quiere ingresar? "))
  for x in range(n):
    identificacion= int(input("INGRESE EL NUMERO DE IDENTIFICACION"))
    nombre=input("INGRESE EL NOMBRE COMPLETO: ")
    correo=input("INGRESE EL CORREO: ")
    telefono=int(input("INGRESE EL NUMERO DE TELEFONO: "))
    fecha_nacimiento=input("INGRESE LA FECHA DE NACIMIENTO SEPARADAS POR PUNTO DD.MM.AA: ")
    nota1=float(input("INGRESE LA PRIMERA NOTA:  "))
    nota2=float(input("INGRESE LA SEGUNDA NOTA:  "))
    nota3=float(input("INGRESE LA TERCERA NOTA:  "))
    nota4=float(input("INGRESE LA CUARTA NOTA : "))
    alumnos[identificacion]=[nombre, [nota1 , nota2 , nota3 , nota4]]
  return alumnos

def buscar_por_identificacion():
  num_i=int(input("Ingrese el numero de IDENTIFICACION DEL ALUMNO"))
  if num_i in alumnos:
    print("LOS DATOS DEL ALUMNO SON",alumnos[num_i])
  else:
    print("NO EXISTE UNA PERSONA CON ESE NUMERO")
```

quiero saber como podria cambiar las notas de los estudiantes ingresandolo por consola

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). En python la indentación (Sangrado) es importante, por favor edita tu código, también agrega las partes faltantes, el array alumnos no aparece en la sección de código que pusiste

Comment: He formateado bien el código (por favor vuelve a editarlo si el identado no está bien, pero en tu original nada estaba identado...). Has puesto en tags `machine-learning`y `base de datos ` cuando en este código, no existe ninguna de las 2. La lista `alumnos` no existe y la referencias. Qué es esa lista? Dónde la declaras? Y se la tendrías que pasar por parámetro a las funciones imagino, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jose. Espero poder ayudarte, para eso tomare algunas suposiciones.

- alumnos es un diccionario, de no ser asi debe replantear la estructura de datos que esta usando.

Cuando haces `alumnos[num_i]` esto trae una lista con dos valores, un str que representa el nombre (es una suposición) y una lista con las notas.

Para hacer el cambio puedes crear una funcion que requerirá la nota que deseas cambiar: Nota 1,2,3 o 4. Las notas en la lista estan en orden, la unica diferencia es que la nota 1 esta en la posición 0, la nota 2 en la posicion 1.

teniendo estos datos puedes hacer algo asi

```
alumno[id_del_alumno][1][que_nota_quiere_cambiar] = la_nueva_nota
```

En donde `id_del_alumno` y `que_nota_quiere_cambiar` se ingresan por input.

Comment: No me hace el cambio de nota :(

Comment: def cambiar_nota():
    num_i=int(input("Ingrese el numero de IDENTIFICACION DEL ALUMNO"))
    if num_i in alumnos:
        numero_nota=int(input("¿Que nota desea cambiar?"))
        numero_nota-=1
        nueva_nota=int(input("¿Cual es la nueva nota?"))
        alumnos[num_i][1][numero_nota]=nueva_nota
    else:
        print("NO EXISTE UNA PERSONA CON ESE NUMERO")